# Negative binomial vs binomial distribution for proportion data

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, glmm, lme4-nlme

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question; I searched around for an answer for some time, but couldn't find anything.

I want to build a model in R, with the proportional number of individuals ('count'/'allCount') as a response variable. 'count' is the number of individuals within a specific group, and 'allCount' the number of individuals with all groups combined. Here is the data, which is a subset for this specific group (a foraging guild of birds, within a larger bird community):

```
"count","allCount","site","treatment","elevation","field.season"
3,20,"CM","fragmented",800,"2016"
4,19,"CM","fragmented",800,"2016"
0,12,"SM","continuous",800,"2016"
1,21,"CA","fragmented",1200,"2016"
3,11,"SA","continuous",1200,"2016"
3,29,"SA","continuous",1200,"2016"
0,16,"SB","continuous",300,"2016"
12,38,"CB","fragmented",300,"2016"
3,22,"SM","continuous",800,"2016"
2,19,"CM","fragmented",800,"2016"
0,22,"SA","continuous",1200,"2016"
3,28,"CA","fragmented",1200,"2016"
15,39,"CB","fragmented",300,"2016"
3,19,"SB","continuous",300,"2016"
15,38,"CA","fragmented",1200,"2017"
12,22,"CA","fragmented",1200,"2017"
3,10,"CM","fragmented",800,"2017"
1,10,"SM","continuous",800,"2017"
1,11,"SM","continuous",800,"2017"
1,17,"CM","fragmented",800,"2017"
5,17,"SA","continuous",1200,"2017"
4,10,"SA","continuous",1200,"2017"
1,21,"SB","continuous",300,"2017"
1,9,"SB","continuous",300,"2017"
1,14,"CB","fragmented",300,"2017"
2,19,"CB","fragmented",300,"2017"
0,6,"CA","fragmented",1200,"2017"
4,14,"SA","continuous",1200,"2017"
2,12,"CM","fragmented",800,"2017"
1,12,"SM","continuous",800,"2017"
2,11,"SB","continuous",300,"2017"
```

---

I have tried three different ways of fitting the data.

---

#### 1. Binomial with lme4

I started with a `binomial` family in the package `lme4`:

```
model1 <- glmer(count/allCount~ (1|site) + treatment + elevation + field.season + 
treatment*elevation + treatment*field.season, family = "binomial", data=dat)
```

Curiously, this first model failed:

```
Error in pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GQmat, compDev = compDev,  : 
Downdated VtV is not positive definite
```

---

#### 2. Binomial with glmmadmb

I then tried fitting the same model in the package `glmmadmb`, this time without the error message:

```
model2 <- glmmadmb(count/allCount~ (1|site) + treatment + elevation + field.season + 
treatment*elevation + treatment*field.season, family = "binomial", data=dat)
```

After checking overdispersion, it seemed like something was wrong with this model, too:

```
> overdisp.glmer(model2)
 Residual deviance: 1848789055.502 on 24 degrees of freedom (ratio: 77032877.313)
```

Here the model fit: 
[image]

---

#### 3. Negative binomial

Finally, I tried fitting the model with a negative binomial distribution. This time, it converged without problems, and the residuals seemed well dispersed:

```
model3 <- glmmadmb(count/allCount*100~ (1|site) + treatment + elevation + field.season + 
          treatment*elevation + treatment*field.season, family = "nbinom", data=dat)
> overdisp.glmer(model3)
  Residual deviance: 21.87 on 24 degrees of freedom (ratio: 0.911)
```

[image]

---

My Question:

1. Is there something conceptually wrong with choosing the negative binomial distribution in this case?
2. Why did my first model fail in the first place / why did the binomial model look so bad?

Comment: The error message has *nothing* to do with validity of your model.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! Do you know what could have caused the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one big conceptual error here and one procedural/programming error (at least).

1. (conceptual) in general, the *negative binomial distribution is not appropriate for proportion data, or count data with an upper bound*. Binomial (or beta-binomial, if you want to allow for additional variation) are appropriate for proportions expressed as counts; Beta is appropriate for proportions with an unknown denominator. You can use count models (Poisson or negative binomial) with an offset if the probability of a successful outcome is low, i.e. the counts are always much less than the maximum possible.
2. (procedural) if expressing a binomial response as a proportion in `glm` or `glmer`, you must include the total number via the `weights` argument, e.g.


   `model1 <- glmer(count/allCount~ (1|site) + treatment*(elevation + field.season) + 
   family = "binomial", weights=allCount, data=dat)`

Comment: Thank you for answering both of my questions! After adding the `weights` argument, the model runs without producing an error.

Comment: Hi @Ben Bolker - I apologise for responding to an old answer, but do you know if there is a good reference for the conceptual concerns? I've come up against a reviewer saying something similar and need to justify my use of quasibinomial as opposed to negative binomial

Comment: Sorry, don't know of anything offhand.  (You could ask a new question referring to this one and specifically looking for literature references ...)