# Negative Binomial having count data with an upper bound

Tags: probability, modeling, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

The general statement is that you cannot use Negative Binomial or Poisson with count data with an upper bound, which makes sense. However, in my case my count data is always much lower than the upper bound. Having $p$ of success very low (in all the randomizations I have made).

EDIT: Regarding whuber answer, here I must be clear that I estimate probabilities through proportions. Sampling until p converges.

Here I show proportions of success for 28800 different count sets:

[image]

Therefore, it is quite improbable that I surpass that upper bound before hitting the required number of failures.

Here: [Negative binomial vs binomial distribution for proportion data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282055/negative-binomial-vs-binomial-distribution-for-proportion-data/282109#282109)

**@Ben Bolker** says that one could use Negative binomial

I have also checked different distributions through $AIC$. Estimating the different parameters of the distributions using *maximum likelihood* and the one that gives me a better fit is the negative binomial. However, as I mentioned we are dealing with an upper bound.

Should I be strict with the basic assumptions of Negative binomial, or could I somehow reason the usage of it through low probability of successes?

Comment: Well people use the normal for things which clearly do not have their support on the real line so I would guess you will be fine but I know no theory to back this up.

Comment: One never actually observes a probability--they are elements of models only--a fact that suggests your "probabilities" really are proportions.  How exactly are they determined?

Comment: You are totally right, I am dealing with proportions. Since I do not really know the probability.  Does it change the problem?

Comment: I have editted to be as correct as I can

Comment: The difference is fundamental, because in taking a proportion you obliterate almost all information about the denominator, which gives you crucial information about the precision with which the proportion is estimated.  This can be ok provided all denominators are the same: would that be the case or not?

Comment: If I understood you properly, for each of the random sets, that are 1000 observations, the denominator is the same. But for each different set It is not. Hope this answers the question, I am not that much into statistics sadly.

Comment: The mean number of successes is estimated from the same number of randomizations(1000). To be more clear, imagine I have 300 sets (A1,...,A300) and I test It against 100 groups(B1,...,B100). Each pair between sets A and B will give me a different upperbound. This upperbound will be set as the length(A1)*length(B1), however in order to get those proportions I randomized 1000 sets with the same denominator length(A1)*length(B1). Then I do the same for the other pairs. Hope this example is clear.